# How does scientific linux 7 get updates while it's based on RHEL 7?

Tags: linux, scientific-linux

Is there any one who can explain the support issues between a licensed product and a open source product which is a "built" of a licensed product?

Comment: what is the problem ? there's no problem RHEL is opensource for most of its code. Centos is based on RHEL and SL as well. RHEL company will only support RHEL product build by them. not the community product.

Comment: Short : The source code is open source. I.e. anybody can build packages from the SRPMs .

Comment: I need to detail "support' over here. For instance I have to have registration to update packages through RHEL licensed product. right?  how does this work for SL?

Answer (score 1):

Scientific Linux is a rebuild of RHEL (permitted by the RHEL license).

Updates are received via the SL channel.

Fermilab, the makers of SL, does not offer support to the general public. Clearly Red Hat doesn't offer support neither as it's a rebuild of their code. However, you can get some support from the [SL community](https://www.scientificlinux.org/community/) as SL is a community-driven project (like CentOS).